# Salesforce @future(callout=true) method is never run

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to make a call out from salesforce most of the code is copied from another working package.

Can anyone tell me why the call out method below is never run?

I am saving into my custom table before and after the call out method is called but the saving into my custom table does not get called with in the call out method.

public class AutoSyncConnector {

```
public AutoSyncConnector()
{

}

public void Fire(string jsonToPost)
{
    // 1. Authentication send the current session id so that request can be validated
   String sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

   // 2. warp the request and post it to the configured end point
   // This is how to get settings out for custom settings list
   String connectorUrl = ASEndPoints__c.getValues('MainUrlEndPoint').autosync__MainSiteUrl__c;

   CastlesMessageLog__c cd = new CastlesMessageLog__c();
   cd.SentJson__c = 'before call out this is called';
   insert cd;

   AutoSyncConnector.CallOut(jsonToPost, connectorUrl);

    CastlesMessageLog__c cd2 = new CastlesMessageLog__c();
    cd2.SentJson__c = 'after call out this is called';
    insert cd2;
}


public static void CallOut(String jsonToPost, String connectorUrl)
{
    MakeCallout(jsonToPost,connectorUrl);
}

@future(callout=true)
public static void MakeCallout(String jsonToPost, String connectorUrl){

    CastlesMessageLog__c cd = new CastlesMessageLog__c();
    cd.SentJson__c = 'start inside before call out this is never called';
    insert cd;

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setTimeout(120000);
   // string authorizationHeader = 'Check I can add stuff to the header';
    String sfdcConnectorUrl = connectorUrl + '/api/autosyncwebhook';
    req.setEndpoint(sfdcConnectorUrl);
    //req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
    req.setBody(jsonToPost);
    h.send(req);

    CastlesMessageLog__c cd2 = new CastlesMessageLog__c();
    cd2.SentJson__c = 'end inside before call out this is never called';
    insert cd2;


}
```

}

Comment: You can ask you question also on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/), it's platform for Salesforce-related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Setup -> Monitoring -> Apex jobs. My gut feel is that you'll see lots of "uncommitted work pending" errors in there.

When you make any DML (insert/update/delete) you open a transaction with the database. If the next thing you'll do is a callout (which can have max timeout time 120 seconds) it'll mean you hold a lock on this record (or even whole table) for very long time. SF has no way of knowing whether the call will succeed or will have to be rolled back. So they protect the situation by banning such code right away ;)

Make callout first, then your DML.

Or make DML, call @future (that's the purpose, to switch to another thread, separate the contexts) and if the callout comes back with error - do whatever cleanup you'd consider a rollback (delete the record? update it to status = Sync failed? Send email to user / insert for him a Task to retry later?)

Comment: This really helped me out thank you :) 
I did not know about "apex jobs monitoring" and after removing all my DML logic i could see that I was posting data to an unauthorised URL many lessons learned here.

Comment: Haha :) Cool. So, just to be clear. If you'll use "Debug logs" or have Developer Console open while experimenting with `@future` - you'll see them in debug log just fine, as an entry separate from your "main one". It's just that if user reports something failed (or a nightly batch job died), you didn't have debug logs - going to Apex jobs is a way to review issues post-mortem.